# Using aws credentials on remote server without storing them on the remote server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssh, remote-server

Is it possible to use aws credentials on remote server without explicitly copying them?

For example I can use my local ssh key on server like `ssh-add && ssh -A <server_name>` is there something like this for aws cli without copying the `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`?

I want to use these aws credentials just to download some files from S3.

Comment: Is your remote server running on Amazon EC2? If so, it is recommended to provide credentials by assigning an IAM Role to the instance rather than using a credentials file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to SSH to a remote server, your public key must already be present on the remote server. Your tool uses the private key to encrypt communications. Therefore, your assumption that your credentials are not needed on the remote server is incorrect.

EC2 supports retrieving credentials from metadata. You could create an IAM role `s3access` and then assume that role inside EC2. You can even retrieve those credentials using the command line tool `curl`. Example:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access
```

Example output:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2012-04-26T16:39:16Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "ASIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  "Token" : "token",
  "Expiration" : "2017-05-17T15:09:54Z"
}
```

Refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for more information on metadata credentials.

You can also setup the CLI to automatically use metadata credentials. Refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-metadata.html) for more information.

If your goal is to have no credentials on the EC2 instance, then you will need to use Presigned URLs. Refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is download some files from S3, [persigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) may be an easier and safer option. AWS allows you to generate URLs for any AWS API action that are only usable for a certain period of time. You can generate those URLs to your specific files, send them to your server, and have the server use them to download the files.

For example:

```
aws s3 presign s3://awsexamplebucket/test2.txt --expires-in 604800
```

All of the different frameworks like boto3 and aws-sdk also support generating URLs.

Another option is generating [temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html). AWS allows lets you create credentials that only for a certain period of time. It also allows you to limit their scope so you can ask that they only allow downloading from a specific bucket, for example. Using STS you will get a new set of access key and session token, send those to your server, and let your server use them to do what it needs to do.

If you want the token to have exactly the same credentials as the calling role, use:

```
aws sts get-session-token
```

Otherwise you will need to create a role with the appropriate permissions and use:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access --role-session-name s3-access-example
```

Just like with presigned URLs, these APIs are available in every SDK and not just on the command line.